# Mutators don't work on mass inserts

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

If I have an array of values I want to do a mass insert on:

```
Item::insert([['price' => 1234.25], ['price' => 4321.75]]);
```

Then my mutators don't fire:

```
public function setPriceAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['price'] = round($value, 2) * 100;
}
```

Unless I break each out into a create:

```
foreach ([['price' => 1234.25], ['price' => 4321.75]] as $new)
    Item::create($new);
```

Am I missing something here? Or will I have to manually apply `round($value, 2) * 100` to each price value within the array?

I have a LOT of records to insert, so a mass insert is most efficient on the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insert` is db and `create` is eloquent. Use `Item::create($new);`, but it'd need to be in a `foreach`.

`insert` is not Eloquent, but can mass insert - but timestamp updating and the works won't be added, etc.

So foreach, might be your best bet here:

```
foreach ($news as $new)
{
    Item::create($new);
}
```

Seems either way you're going to need to do a `foreach` regardless. Either to mutate OR create the records. Pick your poison.